# Python String Logic Error

Tags: python, string

I am currently creating a program that displays the telephone number with any alphabetic characters that appeared in the original translated to their equivalent. For instance, if I were to enter the string "521-BBB-BBBB", I should get "5212222222" based on my code. Instead I got "2222222925" from IDLE. I don't understand why the program showed this instead of the one I was looking for. The number of "2" are correct, but I don't understand where the "925" came from.

This is the code:

```
def charToNum(num):
    if num == 'A' or num == 'B' or num == 'C' or num == '2':
        return '2'
    elif num == 'D' or num == 'E' or num == 'F' or num == '3':
        return '3'
    elif num == 'G' or num == 'H' or num == 'I' or num == '4':
        return '4'
    elif num == 'J' or num == 'K' or num == 'L' or num == '5':
        return '5'
    elif num == 'M' or num == 'N' or num == 'O' or num == '6':
        return '6'
    elif num == 'P' or num == 'Q' or num == 'R' or num == 'S' or num == '7':
        return '7'
    elif num == 'T' or num == 'U' or num == 'V' or num == '8':
        return '8'
    else:
        return '9'
```

def AlphaToTel(telNum):
    newTelNum = telNum[0:3] + telNum[4:7] + telNum[8:12]
    phoneNum = ''
    for char in newTelNum:
        phoneNum = charToNum(char) + phoneNum

print(phoneNum)

AlphaToTel("521-BBB-BBBB")

Comment: You don't handle the number '1` anywhere, so it ends up returning 9 when you enter it. Also, instead of `phoneNum = charToNum(char) + phoneNum`, you may want `phoneNum = phoneNum + charToNum(char)`. That should fix your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because of how your `charToNum()` function is defined (and because of how you are adding the results to `phoneNum`).

Firstly, you are not considering the number `1` in the `charToNum()` , hence you are returning back `9` for `1`. You should consider that and return back `1` , if `num` is `1`.

Secondly, you are adding the phoneNum's as -

```
phoneNum = charToNum(char) + phoneNum
```

This keeps adding the new chars to the beginning of the string, hence you get the phone number in reverse. If you want the output to be something like - `"5212222222"` . You need to add it in the correct order (`phoneNum + charToNum(char)`) or use (`+=`) . Example -

```
phoneNum += charToNum(char)
```

Comment: Why is phoneNum = charToNum(char) + phoneNum different than phoneNum = phoneNum + charToNum(char)? Doesn't addition follow the commutative property?

Comment: For Strings `+` operator means concatenation, and that is not commutative. `AB` is not same as `BA` , is it?

Answer (score 0):

First change `phoneNum = charToNum(char) + phoneNum` to `phoneNum += charToNum(char)` and in your `charToNum` function add one more `if` condition at top to return the `1` when `num` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


def charToNum(num):
    if num in ['1', '0']:
        return num
    elif num in ['A', 'B', 'C', '2']:
        return '2'
    elif num in ['D', 'E', 'F', '3']:
        return '3'
    elif num in ['G', 'H', 'I', '4']:
        return '4'
    elif num in ['J', 'K', 'L', '5']:
        return '5'
    elif num in ['M', 'N', 'O', '6']:
        return '6'
    elif num in ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', '7']:
        return '7'
    elif num in ['T', 'U', 'V', '8']:
        return '8'
    elif num in ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '9']:
        return '9'


def AlphaToTel(telNum):
    telNum = re.findall('(\w)', telNum)
    phoneNum = [charToNum(x) for x in telNum]
    print(''.join(phoneNum))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AlphaToTel("521-BBB-BBBB")
```